# Ubuntu + Royal Kludge RK71 bluetooth paired but many keys dont work some type wrong alphabets

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

Has anyone had success paring a royal kludge with ubuntu 19.04 or 18.10 its working fine in wired mode but bluetooth mode its a mess.

It got paired and connected but only a handful of keys are working and that too numbers.

If someone has suggestions i am all ears.

Comment: Have you tried pairing it to another device, such as a smartphone, just for testing?

Comment: I have successfully paired with Windows 10 Laptop and Desktop, Android Phones, Mac Mini, Raspberry Pi 3 and it works great via bluetooth. it just refuses to work properly after pairing on ubuntu, the drivers might be a miss but it works correct when connected via wire to ubuntu. so its the bluetooth drivers that get assigned might be the issue. i tried on two ubuntu desktops and this yielded me the same results.

Comment: How does this work in wired mode? I am planning to buy one? Any suggestions for a keyboard that works well for Ubuntu?